# Building a container with debootstrap

Tags: arm, lxc

I'm trying to create a LXC container (lxc-create) and I get this error:

```
E: Invalid Release file, no entry for main/binary-armhf/Packages
```

any way to fix this?

This is what happens:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# lxc-create -n myfirstcontainer -t debian
Note: Usually the template option is called with a configuration file option too, mostly to configure the network. For more information look at lxc.conf (5)
Downloading minimal system...
I: Retrieving Release
W: Cannot check Release signature; keyring file not available /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg
E: Invalid Release file, no entry for main/binary-armhf/Packages
Failed to download the rootfs, aborting.
Failed to download base system
failed to install system
failed to execute template 'debian'
aborted
```

Comment: Show us some code ... in the question. You can edit your question.

Comment: Here I describe a minimal working amd64 and arm64 QEMU Ubuntu `debootstrap` setup that might be of interest: https://askubuntu.com/questions/281763/is-there-any-prebuilt-qemu-ubuntu-image32bit-online/1081171#1081171